# Wrong Characters while exporting MYSQL data table from website to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I found solutions here but still got problems.
I have data table in my website which one uses Georgian Fonts, in my MYSQL database those fonts are displayed normally but when I try to download this table using export.php in my PC with .csv file the fonts are like

> áƒ’áƒáƒ¡áƒáƒ¡áƒ•áƒšáƒ”áƒšáƒ¨áƒ˜

In my export.php the code is below:

```
if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {   
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('არდუინოს N','ტრანზაქცია', 'User ID', 'Transaction Date', 'Object Name', 'Terminal Name', 'Amount'));  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE userID='$userID' ORDER BY trID DESC"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }
```

Download works fine I got file data.csv but inside this file characters are unrecognized 
[Link for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMhvu.png)

Any ideas? What is wrong ?
If you think that is duplicated Question then I can tell you NO because before posting here I found lots of same solutions but nothing helps 
In my database connection php file I have added

```
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

and

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
```

But nothing changed... Any tips what would cause this problem would be great, Thank you guys in advance...

Comment: It looks like the screenshot is of Excel or some other spreadsheet application. Are your sure that application reads the CSV file as UTF-8 encoded file? What do you see if you open the CSV file with a text editor in UTF-8 mode (e.g. using Notepad++ if you're on Windows?)